# Reference book for general Topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds

My professor is currently using the schaum's series book for general Topology. I have munkers topology book as reference but the issue is I am not understanding munkers book at all. I somewhere read the book "Introduction to topological manifolds by lee" is good for general Topology as well as Algebraic Topology. So my question is should I use this book as reference? As alternate for munkers book.

**My background**: I had took first course in linear algebra. And currently studying *analysis 1 by tao* - second chapter, *contemporary abstract algebra by gallian* - 3rd chapter, *How to prove it an structural approach* - 1st chapter.

Comment: Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis by Simmons.

Comment: You mean reference or introduction? There are some very good references but not that good for learning if you don't have the time.

Comment: That said Munkres book is a standard introduction to the subject.

Comment: @geetha290krm I will check it. Thank you

Comment: @Jakobian Yes munkers book is standard. But I am not understanding concepts , maybe because of weak background. And i am taking about reference but as well as introductory because i think schaum's series book is not standard for learning subject it is for review or practice.

Comment: I didn't read Schaum's General topology, but it looks like a good book to ease yourself in general topology. What problems did you encounter when trying to read it?

Comment: @Jakobian There is less theory of topics, some proofs are difficult for me to understand like theorem 4.2 says "the intersection of any finite number of open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ is open" and the author says in proof "we prove the theorem in the case of two open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$.  And plus point is there are alot of solved examples.

Comment: About the open sets of the plane, you do this by induction. First, you prove intersection of two open sets is open, then you assume intersection of any $n\geq 2$ open sets is open, and you prove it for $n+1$ open sets. I'm afraid you will have to get used to this kind of argument because most if not all authors will skip this without any mention, since it's very intuitive.

Comment: @Jakobian I understood. So overall I continue the book, and for reference should i keep a book? Like munkers or lee topological manifolds or simmons book?

Comment: I think Munkres or Lee will just confuse you because they don't start from topology in $\mathbb{R}^n$ like Schaum seems to do. I don't know about Simmons since I heard of it.

Comment: @Jakobian Oh. Okay so I think it is better to follow schaum's series book gor topology then after doing reasonable amount of topology, i use munkers or lee. Thank you so suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. That sounds like a good plan